# A reference about Grassmannian over finite fields

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, finite-fields, grassmannians

Suppose $Gr_k(k,n)$ the Grassmannian which classifies all the dimension $k+1$ sub-spaces of a dimension $n+1$ linear space over the field $k$. For the case over a finite field $\mathbb F_{q}$, we can calculate the number of $Gr_{\mathbb F_q}(k,n)(\mathbb F_q)$.

Could someone give me a direct reference of this result? I know it is not very hard to calculate, but for some reasons I don't want to write the calculation in my paper but I need a reference for this. Thank you.

Comment: I would just write the result without bothering with a reference or a proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics Volume I* (2nd Edition), Proposition 1.7.2. But like Ben I think not including a proof or reference would probably be fine.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

See [Vogan's notes.](http://www-math.mit.edu/~dav/grassmann.pdf) And here are more characters.

Comment: I know his notes. But actually I want a "published" reference. Thank you.